# python: index out of range in a simple program

Tags: python

in the following program I got the index out of range error:

```
def evaluate(x, y):
    result = 0
    for i in x:
        result += (x[i])*(y**i)
    return result
```

Comment: `for i in x:` causes i to iterate through the values stored in the array, not the indexes of the values (like javascript does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already looping over all values of `x`, no need to then index them again:

```
def evaluate(x, y):
    result = 0
    for i in x:
        result += i * (y**i)
    return result
```

Compare the following two:

```
>>> x = [3, 2]
>>> for i in x:
...     print i
...
3
2
>>> for i in x:
...     print x[i]
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you expected `i` to be an index into `x`, use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get that index:

```
def evaluate(x, y):
    result = 0
    for i, value in enumerate(x):
        result += value * (y**i)
    return result
```

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty noob in python. by your code how can I distinguish between the first i which is the content of x[i] and the second i (y**i) which is the index itself?

Comment: @Hessam: see the latter part of the answer, use `enumerate()` where `i` is the index and `value` is the content of `x[i]`.

Comment: Thanks everybody, enumerate saved the day